# Angular 2 cancel requests on route change

Tags: angular

How to cancel requests on Angular 2 route change?
Because now on route change request is going and values in subscribe are set as well on preview component.

Comment: What request? What route change? Please provide the code that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is reproducible in any case, this is how angular 2 works by default.

Comment: Your question should still provide more information. What request are you talking about?

Comment: You want to detect only route change ? and which request http calling ?

Comment: http.
for example, i make request onInit in component, don't wait until response and switch to another route, but i see in console, that in hidden route response comes and is set to class variable.

Comment: You can create a `Subscription` for each of your calls and then unsubscribe in `OnDestroy` or similar events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to router events like this whenever route is changed this will be fired and store your http subscription into a variable and if router event accured you can unsubscribe to that.

```
class MyClass implements OnInit {
 constructor(private router: Router) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)).subscribe((event) => {
    // here you can unsubscribe your http call 
  });
 }
}
```